# Android Emulator appears in strange UI

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-10.0

I am trying to create and run an AVD from command line using [Android's Command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line).

This means I used the `sdkmanager` to download the following modules:

- platform-tools
- emulator
- build-tools;29.0.2
- platforms;android-29
- system-images;android-29;default;x86_64

Afterwards I created an AVD using `call avdmanager create avd --name android29 --package "system-images;android-29;default;x86_64"` where I selected `no` for `Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile? [no]`.

When launching the AVD using `emulator @android29` and booting it up afterwards I get an old-fashioned bootscreen followed by an old-fashioned homescreen. The settings page however shows that Android 10 is in use.

What is the meaning or the reason of the old-fashioned looking UI?

[image: Screenshot Bootscreen]
[image: Screenshot Homescreen]
[image: Screenshot Android Version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by using `system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86_64` instead of `"system-images;android-29;default;x86_64"`.

Answer (score 0):

Because I fall here using a different config (Android 11 instead of 10, and using the Android Studio Console instead of the cli), but got the exact same error I thing it might help someone who is facing the same issue to mention that by just using the Android 10 from the console, the issue disappears (if using Android 10 is an option instead of 11, like my case).

[screenshot of Android choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rekuT.png)